# Sql error aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

From CTE (common table expression) I get this data

**For Ex:**

```
col1, col2, col3
AUDI  ROOM_1 5 
AUDI  ROOM_1 10 
BMW   ROOM_1 1 
BMW   ROOM_1 2
```

**Now I need get**

```
col1, col2, col3
AUDI  ROOM_1 15 
BMW   ROOM_1 3
```

**I'm try this Query..**

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from cte

GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
(
    (col1,col2) 
)
```

> But i'm Getting this type of Error..

Column 'cte.col3' is invalid in the Select List because it is not contained in either an Aggregate Function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Too basic sample data. Let one BMW have ROOM_2, and show us the new result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use aggregation

```
Select col1, col2, sum(col3) from cte
group by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select col1, col2, CAST(SUM(col3)AS INT) AS col3  from cte
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

**use GROUP BY**